# Plotly Dash Can't Put div in the Same Row

Tags: html, row, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

On a Plotly Dash dashboard, I am unable to get my graphs to  stretch as the screen grows then be side by side in one row once the screen get's big enough. If I use style={"float:right"} and style={"float:left"} with each graph, it will work, but the graphs will not stretch with the screen anymore. I have attached a photo of the resulting plots. The plots are over/under. I want them side by side with a large browser window, then to shrink with a medium browser window and be over/under with a small browser window.

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Checklist(
        id='input',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Astoria', 'value': 'AST'},
            {'label': 'Warrenton', 'value': 'WAR'},
            {'label': 'Seaside', 'value': 'SEA'}
        ],
        values=['AST', 'WAR', 'SEA'],
    ),
    html.Div(className='row',
             children=[
        html.Div(
            dcc.Graph(id='value-index'),
            className='col s12 m6', 
            ),
        html.Div(
            dcc.Graph(id='rental-index'),
            className='col s12 m6',
            )
        ],

    )


])


@app.callback(
    Output('value-index', 'figure'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='values')]
    )

def update_graph(input_data):

    return  {
            'data': [
                {'x': astoriaValueIndex.index, 'y': astoriaValueIndex.Value, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'Astoria'},
                {'x': warrentonValueIndex.index, 'y': warrentonValueIndex.Value, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'Warrenton'},
                {'x': seasideValueIndex.index, 'y': seasideValueIndex.Value, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'Seaside'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Zillow Value Index'
            }
        }


@app.callback(
    Output('rental-index', 'figure'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='values')]
    )

def update_graph(input_data):

    return {
            'data': [
                {'x': astoriaRentalIndex.index, 'y': astoriaRentalIndex.Value, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'Astoria'},
                {'x': warrentonRentalIndex.index, 'y': warrentonRentalIndex.Value, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'Warrenton'},
                {'x': seasideRentalIndex.index, 'y': seasideRentalIndex.Value, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'Seaside'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Zillow Rental Index'
            }
        }
    [enter image description here][1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you try with CSS option : display : Flex; ?

```
html.Div(className='row',
         style = {'display' : 'flex'},
             children=[
        html.Div(
            dcc.Graph(id='value-index'),
            className='col s12 m6',

            ),
        html.Div(
            dcc.Graph(id='rental-index'),
            className='col s12 m6',
            )
        ],
```

Normally, this should update the page according to the way you want.

Comment: Thank you Quentin. it solved my problem.